# Are the only generators of a Cyclic Group $G=\langle g\rangle$, where $|g| = \infty$, $g$ and $g^{-1}$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

I'm self studying group theory, and this is a question in the textbook I've taken out, there is no answer given so I'm assuming that's because it's too simple to require one. I'm almost certain that the only generators are $g$ and $g^{-1}$, because the group is not finite, so for no $g^n$ can, say, ${(g^n)}^q = 1$, correct?

Comment: Try taking another generator, and see what you can get!

Comment: Hint: such group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, to whoever put my question in proper notation, I was just figuring out how to do it myself

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

If $g^n$ is another generator, then for some $k$ you can get $g^{nk} = g$. Can $G$ be infinite then?

Comment: No, because then $g^{nk-1}$ = 1, so there'd only be a finite number of elements in the group, thanks

Comment: @Nethesis exactly, well done!

Comment: ... unless $nk=1$ ...

Comment: Yes, you must add that $n\neq \pm 1$

Answer (score 0):

Any infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to Z
And Z has only two generators namely 1 and -1